# How to layout irregular shapes in Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, custom-component

So my graphics artist came to me with a really cool layout for controls on our new app.  The problem is getting these images laid out since most views in android are rectangular.  See image for what I have to work with.

Any idea how to layout these buttons so they shape around each other if that makes sense?

[image]

Comment: Create your own custom layout.It would be much easier and efficient than hacking in built layouts.Let me know if you need some help on this along with what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the layout, you can draw the buttons and save it as png. You can layout your app by RelevantLayout . And use the "selector" to change the button image when user press an so on.

selector example: "drawable/selector1.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/buttonClicked" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/buttonClicked" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

use it like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/selector1"
```

Comment: The problem is how do I layout the buttons so the half moon button is nested between the corner buttons.  If I use RelativeLayout and set the half moon below the corner buttons it will not look like the image above.

Comment: I said save the buttons as png . look here I did it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11906926/fine.JPG and also you should manage some button in the back some in the front. Regards

Answer (score 0):

the `Views` in android are rectangular, that is correct. The only workaround I see here: use multiple "invisible" `Buttons` (alpha set to 0). You can position them around the screen and assign the same action to some of them. Of course you'll need to implement the `OnClickListener` and use switch-case.

Comment: Im not sure I could do that.  I need the half moon shaped button to be nested between the corner buttons, if I do it like you suggest the top of the half moon button would be below the corner buttons wouldnt it?